# Explanation of NetworkStream.Read behaviour needed

Tags: vb.net, networkstream

I am consuming real-time data from a network stream using a blocking read as follows:

```
Do
  NetworkStream.Read(Bytes, 0, ReceiveBufferSize)
  'Do stuff with data here
Loop
```

Watching packets come in on the wire in Wireshark, I see that sometimes when a new packet comes in, .NET sees it immediately and unblocks, letting me process it. Other times, multiple packets will come in on the wire before the NetworkStream.Read unblocks and returns the whole lot in one go - I've seen up to 8 packets buffer before the NetworkStream read unblocks.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to grab and process each packet immediately as it is received across the wire? Will an Async receive model make any difference here? Or am I just fundamentally misunderstanding the way that TCP streams work?